# warning mysql_fetch_assoc () expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result boolean given in

Tags: mysql

```
require('includes/database.php');
$db = new Database();
echo "<table border = 1 width=100%>
<tr>
<th> ID </th>
<th> Login ID </th>
</tr>";


$result = $db->select('test','*');
foreach($result as $row)
{
        /*$ID = $row['SID'];
        $fname = $row[First_Name];
        $lname = $row[Last_Name];
        $pwd = $row[Password];
        $email= $row[Email];*/              

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center'>". $row['ID'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>". $row['Name'] ."</td>";
        echo "</tr><br>";
}
```

The above code is giving me the warning "warning mysql_fetch_assoc () expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result boolean given in" but if I replace the table to "system_user" in select statement it works fine with me. Please advice!

Comment: the code for database.php would help alot

Comment: The message suggests you're mixing mysqli and mysql functions, but I'd bet the real reason is a syntax error in the SQL Query generated inside `database.php`

Comment: This is not the actual code where that error is happening.  Show the code from database.php as well such that it is clear how your `select()` method works.

Comment: Do you actually have a table called `test`?

Comment: Thankyou everyone for respose, I was having some error in database.php for select function :)